# How can an array of python of zeros and ones pass to binary file?

Tags: python, binary, raster

I have an array in Python of zeros and ones, zero for non water and one for water, this difference is only for the shape of any river. Then I was trying of this array pass to binary file, but then I was try to open and only have zeros in data and some values of 63, I don´t undestand why?

I was trying with the command numpy array and to file when the format select binary , the file with visor of binary files only have zeros and some values of 64 and the shape of river is loss.

```
ds = gdal.Open("C:\\Users\\ASUS\\Documents\\cauce1991_1142grasscorr1991.tif")
myarray = np.array(ds.GetRasterBand(1).ReadAsArray())

entero = myarray.astype(int)

matrixbinaria = np.array(entero).tofile("binaryo2",format="b")
```

I required only a binary file of zeros and ones for realize other measurements like widths

Comment: What, *exactly* is the output you require?

Comment: It's fun to guess what the PO is trying to ask. I think the input file `*.tif` is a binary (B/W) image of a river.  The PO wants to have an array of 0 and 1 only, but somehow the output contains 0 and 63.

Comment: Initially I begin with a tif file that transform in array of zeros and ones, this array I need convert to binary file equal to this file Testohio_channel 1b : https://www.dropbox.com/s/xjx416dw3ppp256/Testohio_channel_1b?dl=0, this file was created in fortran and run good in aplication that need. After I have an array of only zeros and ones I want to convert to binary file of this form:

Comment: See file : https://www.dropbox.com/s/rwd42odzq8702oo/binaryprueba.py?dl=0


"Convert array to binary"
entero= myarray2.astype(int)
matrixbinaria = np.array(entero).tofile("binaryo2",format="b")

Comment: I try to pass array to binary with datatype int, but open any visor only have zeros and ones but the shape of river is loss, i don´t kow why but if you can see this file created like txt https://www.dropbox.com/s/zx2m1lyu5k5v86o/arraytexto3.txt?dl=0  , the array is good. I think my problem is that my outputfile is not equal to testohio file, that have an array of zeros and ones , I don´t understand why this happens.